# Firebase Notification - How to set language of a notification?

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to send notifications to devices based on their languages.
My first idea was to create a push for each locales availables in server side, and let Firebase do all the dispaching work.

But for that I need to set the locale for every push.

I haven't found any parameters available for that, so I would like to know if I am right or if I need to change my design. And if I have to do so, what should I do ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using a topic for each language, and then subscribing each client to the topic of its locale? Then when you [send a message to the topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics) for a locale, the users who subscribed to that topic will get it.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to me to be the best solution. Thanks !